# calculate prices of Batches automatically

Tags: c

I am trying to make profit type thingy. For now I am doing Cookies and am doing the profits of individual batches, using the prices of the ingredients and how many batches they last to find the profit, however, the LCM is 300 so I can't really do it manually. So how would I go about do this automatically?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define buttergram 500
#define sugargram 1000
#define eggsgram 12
#define flourgram 1000
#define bakingpowdergram 100
#define chocchipsgram 200

#define butterbatch 125
#define sugarbatch 200
#define eggsbatch 2
#define flourbatch 300
#define bakingpowderbatch 4
#define chocchipsbatch 200

int main()
{
    /* Variables */

    float butter;
    float sugar;
    float eggs;
    float flour;
    float bakingpowder;
    float chocchips;

    char pound = 156;

    /* Actual Code */

    printf("How much were the 500g of Golden Cow Butter?: %c" ,pound);
    scanf("%f" ,&butter);
    printf("\n");
    printf("How much were the 1000g of Soft Brown Sugar?: %c" ,pound);
    scanf("%f" ,&sugar);
    printf("\n");
    printf("How much were the 12 Eggs?: %c" ,pound);
    scanf("%f" ,&eggs); 
    printf("\n");
    printf("How much were the 1000g of Flour?: %c" ,pound);
    scanf("%f" ,&flour);    
    printf("\n");
    printf("How much were the 100g of Baking Powder?: %c" ,pound);
    scanf("%f" ,&bakingpowder);
    printf("\n");
    printf("How much were the 200g Chocolate Chips?: %c" ,pound);
    scanf("%f" ,&chocchips);    
    printf("\n");


    printf("The butter will last %d batches which means you are paying %c%.2f for 1 batch.\n" ,buttergram/butterbatch ,pound ,butter/(buttergram/butterbatch));
    printf("The sugar will last %d batches which means you are paying %c%.2f for 1 batch.\n" ,sugargram/sugarbatch ,pound ,sugar/(sugargram/sugarbatch));
    printf("The eggs will last %d batches which means you are paying %c%.2f for 1 batch.\n" ,eggsgram/eggsbatch ,pound ,eggs/(eggsgram/eggsbatch));
    printf("The flour will last %d batches which means you are paying %c%.2f for 1 batch.\n" ,flourgram/flourbatch ,pound ,flour/(flourgram/flourbatch));
    printf("The baking powder will last %d batches which means you are paying %c%.2f for 1 batch.\n" ,bakingpowdergram/bakingpowderbatch ,pound ,bakingpowder/(bakingpowdergram/bakingpowderbatch));
    printf("The chocolate chips will last %d batch which means you are paying %c%.2f for 1 batch.\n" ,chocchipsgram/chocchipsbatch ,pound ,chocchips/(chocchipsgram/chocchipsbatch));

    /* How many Batches ingredients last */

    int butterbatches = buttergram/butterbatch;
    /* 4 */
    int sugarbatches = sugargram/sugarbatch;
    /* 5 */
    int egssbatches = eggsgram/eggsbatch;
    /* 6 */
    int flourbatches = flourgram/flourbatch;
    /* 3 is actually 3.33 */
    int bakingpowderbatches = bakingpowdergram/bakingpowderbatch;
    /* 25 */
    int chocchipsbatches = chocchipsgram/chocchipsbatch;
    /* 1 */

    printf("Remember a batch is 24 cookies.\n");
    printf("Batch 1: %c%.2f has been spent which is %c%.2f per cookie.\n" ,pound ,butter+sugar+eggs+flour+bakingpowder+chocchips ,pound ,(butter+sugar+eggs+flour+bakingpowder+chocchips)/24);
    printf("Batch 2: %c%.2f has been spent which is %c%.2f per cookie.\n" ,pound ,chocchips ,pound ,chocchips/24);
    printf("Batch 3: %c%.2f has been spent which is %c%.2f per cookie.\n" ,pound ,chocchips ,pound ,chocchips/24);
    printf("Batch 4: %c%.2f has been spent which is %c%.2f per cookie.\n" ,pound ,flour+chocchips ,pound ,(flour+chocchips)/24);
    printf("Batch 5: %c%.2f has been spent which is %c%.2f per cookie.\n" ,pound ,chocchips+butter ,pound ,(chocchips+butter)/24);
    printf("Batch 6: %c%.2f has been spent which is %c%.2f per cookie.\n" ,pound ,sugar+chocchips ,pound ,(flour+chocchips+butter)/24);
    printf("Batch 7: %c%.2f has been spent which is %c%.2f per cookie.\n" ,pound ,eggs+chocchips ,pound ,(eggs+chocchips)/24);
    printf("This cycle goes on for 300 batches so until I find an automatic method you get the idea.");

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Honestly for this particular task Excel formulae might be more suitable

Comment: You need variables to store the amount of ingredients you bought. If they are enough to bake a batch, then subtract the amounts needed for a batch from that variables. If some ingredients are missing, then buy them (increase your ingredients on stock and increase your expenses accordingly). Continue this until all your ingredients on stock are empty. You need to do this in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I recommend cracking open your books or whatever other learning resources you have and babystepping a little further before you attempt to write these types of programs.

As you learned the hard way, when you have a large number of elements, you don't want to be writing a separate line of code for every single thing you could ever do with them on an individual basis.

Here you want to learn about control structures, your `for/while/do-while` loops, arrays to store elements that are indexable (allowing you to retrieve the nth element from a collection of them), possibly even file I/O and `structs` to define your own data types.